# List of methods in class

Tags: ruby, list, methods

So, I want to do a list of methods and after use that list in for-loop.

```
 

    class Hello
        def func
            pass
        end
        def func1
            pass
        end
        list = [func, func1]
        def loop_func
            for func_instance in list
                func_instance
            end
        end
end
```

But this code does not work. What is wrong?

Comment: For class `A` and `a=A.new`, `A.instance_methods` or `a.methods` will give you an array of the class' instance methods. Use `A.instance_methods(false)` or `a.methods(false)` to include only instance methods defined on the class (i.e., to exclude inherited instance methods that are not overwritten).

Comment: Ok. And how I can run function from that list?

Comment: Methods can be called programmatically with `send`. Check out http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Object.html#method-i-send

Comment: Correction: "Use `A.instance_methods(false)` or `a.class.instance_methods(false)` to include only...".

Comment: My apologies for the tardy replay. @rossettistone provides good advice. Suppose your class contains the methods: `def func; puts "func"; end` and `def func1; puts "func1";  end`.  Then you'd write `loop_func` like this: `def loop_func; m = self.class.instance_methods(false) - [:loop_func]; puts "m=#{m}"; m.each { |m| send m }; end`. You would then invoke `loop_func` on an instance of `Hello`: `hello = Hello.new; hello.loop_func` then prints `"func"` and `"func1"`. Note I had to subtract `:loop_func` from the list of methods. The `puts` is just for debugging.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Hello
  def foo
    p "Foo"
  end
  def bar
    p "Bar"
  end
  def loop_methods
    self.class.instance_methods(false)
      .each{ |m| m == __method__ || self.send(m) }
  end
end

Hello.new.loop_methods
```